# Опечатка в браузере хром

Tags: nginx, google-chrome

Коллеги, подскажите что за магия произошла. Случайно в адресной строке браузера хром набрал `v/` нажал `enter`. Появился сервер. Но у меня нет никакого сервера на пк. Что это может означать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Значит, есть. У меня такого нет, хотя есть сервер денвер.

Comment: А это ваш IP-адрес?

Comment: Alexey Ten, нет айпи не мой

Answer (score 0):

Загляните в файл [hosts](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts).
Вероятнее всего у вас там есть запись, которая резолвит адрес `v/` в этот ip

Comment: в хосте ничего нет